# How to setup a WebForms authentication web app to connect to SSAS?

Tags: ssas, webforms

I'm trying to connect a web forms application to an SSAS Cube. The app is using web forms authentication and it is using web roles in Azure. The SSAS cube is on a Virtual Machine within Azure. There is no domain installed. The web app is using [GrapeCity's Active Analysi](http://www.gcpowertools.com/products/ActiveAnalysis)s control. When running the app i get the error "An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host". While profiling on the server I get an "Anonymous Logon" attempt.

How can I set this up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SSAS uses Windows authentication only, so either:

1) You somehow get your web app's application pool to run under a windows account that can access the cube box (Sounds unlikely).

2) You have your application pool run under a windows account and create a windows account with the same username/password on the cube box, and assign it the permissions (Used to work, I think it still does).

3) You allow Anonymous Logon read permissions to your cube. I know you can do this at the server level (Dev enviroments..), I haven't tried it at the cube role level.

These are the ones I know of, best of luck.

EDIT: Sorry, thought I'd forgotten one, there is basic authentication if you add IIS as an extra layer, you have to set it up to go via the MSDMPump.dll, full explanation here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg492140.aspx

Comment: I ended up using the MSMDPump.dll ISAPI. Works like a charm!